# Remove Semicolon From Model.Count() Function

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, count, model

I want to count a model, for that I used the `Count` function:

```
@Model.Count(d => d.Example == Example.ExampleAlive);
```

It works perfect, but the problem is, that there is a semicolon at the end, which i cant remove.

Thanks for your help!

Regards
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of code you have shown is from a Razor view and that line of code is **inline** rather than part of a code block (code blocks are wrapped with `@{ }`.

Inline statements in a Razor view do **not** require a semicolon at the end -- so if you do include the semicolon as part of the inline statement, **it will get rendered in your output**.

To fix your problem simply remove the semicolon.

`@Model.Count(d => d.Example == Example.ExampleAlive)`